# MongoDB data storing

Tags: mongodb

maybe is a silly question but I am really wondering where is going to be stored the whole data? If I am looking for this /data/db there is no folder called like this in my root folder on MacOS. Can anyone explain to me how is this work?

Comment: If i am getting negatives I am waiting for a explanation if you really think that you're too smart and I am deserving that

Comment: I guess you are downvoted because: a) your question is off-topic b) is poorly asked even for the suitable http://dba.stackexchange.com and c) Does not show any efforts for solving this yourself or - forgive me - basic understanding of the OS you are using. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Well, apparently that /data/db is going to be in my Macintosh HD but those files are full 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000, when you're asking me to show you something that is a proof of my efforts or my "basic" skills of OS you prefer a short clip of how I approach to access that root? As per your your quick links that is going to show me "How to ask a good question" there is a sentence that say "Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some." Well here is not about any code. I was just looking for a folder in my root

Comment: but they sure all benefit from proper research;) don't take it personally (I know I sound rude from time to time, sorry if I hurt your feelings), but as a hint on how to improve. Hint 2; "cd /; find . -type f -name mongod.conf"

Answer (score 0):

You have to either create that directory yourself, or specify a different location with

```
mongod --dbpath=/path/to/dir/db
```

I usually create a directory called `db` in my project directory and use that

```
mongod --dbpath=/home/tim/project/db
```

Comment: I have already created Users-iMac-2:~ user$ mkdir -p /data/db

Comment: @FlapJack then it's probably not in the right location

Comment: it is created and its working if I runt ./mongo and use show dbs it will show me the collections

Answer (score 0):

Open your Database configuration file.

Look `dbpath` variable.

For example

```
dbpath = /srv/mongodb
```